# How to make an SVG element invisible but still react to onMouseUp

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to hide an svg-group when the user clicks on it. If the user clicks on the spot where the svg-group was before it was hidden (it should still be there, you just can't see it) then it should reappear. Which css property do I have to use to achieve that? Or is the `onmouseup` the wrong property?

I tried using `visibility: hidden` and `display: none` but both do not work.

Here my svg:

```
<g onmouseup="fnClickedSVGGroup(this)">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
    <text x="5" y="5">Click me!</text>
</g>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried using `visibility: hidden` and `display: none`, but neither one works. Instead, try using the `opacity` property in CSS.

Answer (score 3):

You can use visibility: hidden as long as you also set the [pointer-events property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pointer-events) accordingly.

You can't use display:none as that causes the element not to exist at all.

```html
<svg>
<g visibility="hidden" pointer-events="all" onmouseup="alert('hi')">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
    <text x="5" y="5">Click me!</text>
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `opacity`in css:

```
g {
  opacity: 0;
}
```